# No Android SDK Found. - Android Studio - React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

Despite successfully installing the Android SDK and platform, and even after restarting, I encounter the error "No Android SDK Found" when launching Android Studio.

[image]

Upon clicking "Next," the path corresponds with my local directory as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the android studio, and reinstall it at another path, like you can install it in another folder, just change the path. Install it again and it will download the sdk tools.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that your terminal doesn't have the paths.
You can run something like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```